# Excel Vertical data to Horizontal structure

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm after a way to convert the following vertical table structure

[image]

*Note: I don't care about the 3 rows after the first two columns*

To a horizontal structure
[image]

Comment: paste special: transpose

Comment: research unpivot :)

Comment: I just learned about unpivot and having the guilt to share a very native solution when such a powerful feature is available. Learned something good. Thanks for highlighting it. Thanks @ScottHoltzman

Comment: However @ScottHoltzman, I researched further in order to improve my answer and found that UnPivot is not helpful in particular here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original data as below in Sheet1.

[image: Original Data]

It is pretty much achievable by doing below steps:

1. Remove Duplicates (Data -> Remove Duplicates) / Filter the Unique values of Column (Filter -> Copy to another location -> Unique Records Only)

[image: Desired Data]

2. Use the below formula which is a combination of [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66), [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34), [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) in the Sheet2 cell B1 and drag right and down to get the desired result as shown in the image above.

   =IF(COLUMN(B2)-1<=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A1),INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A1),1),COLUMN(B2)-1),"")

Note: Step 1 is not explained in detail as I assumed that the reader(s) have basic understanding of MS Excel. If you are not aware of removing duplicates, try searching Stackoverflow website and you'll find lot of articles.